# What IP went down?

Tags: networking, monitoring

currently I have a problem. I have a switch and have no idea, what port is connected to what PoE device. Now I'd like to solve this issue. My idea is to disable a PoE port on the switch and wait what IP went down.

But how can I do this?
Is there a tool, that can ping all IPs in the net and show what IP just went down?

Answer (score 1):

For an IPv4 LAN try [`arp-scan`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arp-scan). It sends arp packets and collects the responses.

Install it e.g. via apt:

```
sudo apt install arp-scan
```

Here is an example to scan all IPs in your LAN connected to the interface `eth0`:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

Pipe the output of the scans to two files `before.dat` and `after.dat` and compare them via

```
diff before.dat after.dat
```

Comment: And how can I get, what device went down? I have to compare the output manually. And with 200+ IPs it's quite annoying.

Comment: pipe the result before and after to files and compare the files.